# convert an ipad app to iphone app with custom views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, scale, ios-universal-app

This might be a repeat question.But i have a problem. I have an iPad app functional. The app is built in iOS 6. When i started building it i chose iPad as targeted device NOT universal. Now my client has asked for an iPhone version of it.In my iPad app i keep adding custom views as the client clicks "Add More".I add a custom view which is  bunch of textfields, buttons etc.So i copied my iPad app and changed the Targeted device family to iPhone once and also Universal next time and tested it. So when i launch the app in iPhone configuration (keeping the targeted device family as Universal) my view controller stays like that on iPad. I cannot scroll the app also(not up/down..nor sideways). Is this the correct way to convert iPad app to iPhone app . Also everything is still with scale to iPad. Should i start a new project and start everything from scratch.Set the storyboard to fit according to iPhone configuration? In my research people said just change the targeted device family to Universal. But it doesn't work. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert the current project you have to an app that can be used universally, but it would take more time than simply just creating a new project that allows universal usage, and adding in the files of which you used for your iPad project.

Hint: You can use more than one storyboard when the project was created universally. It will automatically set this up for you.

I would also advise that you separate your files into what works universally, and what is specific for the iPhone or the iPad.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks. I am doing that now.I have 2 storyboards one for iPad and iPhone. Now i have this issue with controls. I have many controls on iPad. So can you give me an idea as to how to reduce the size of the controls to fit iPhone screen. Or should i have like 2/3 view controllers instead of 1 like on iPad.

Comment: No, you have two storyboards because the iPad and the iPhone operate differently. I can't advise you what to do unless I saw the layout of the app. What I will say is that you are going to need to re-design the iPhone storyboard to reflect the capabilities of the iPhone. Otherwise, you have a good chance of alienating users.

Answer (score 0):

After many search i found that it possible to have an application for both Iphone and ipad devices.but in your code you should define unique ui for each device(two xib file).